# Help on finding the closed form of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, closed-form

Can anyone help me to find closed solution of the integral
$$\int_0^{1-e^{-\lambda x}}\frac{u^{b-1}\,(1-u)^{a+c-1}}{[1-(1-e^{-\lambda_1 t_1})u]^{a+b+c}}\,{\rm d}u,$$

where $a,b,c,t_1,\lambda,\lambda_1>0\,.$

Comment: Looks like a  $ _2F_1$ type integral

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You have an Euler-type integral, you may then rewrite your initial integral in terms of the [Appel hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations)
$$
F_1(a,b_1,b_2,c;x,y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_0^1\frac{v^{a-1}(1-v)^{c-a-1}}{(1-xv)^{-b_1}(1-yv)^{-b_2}}~dv
$$ where $\Re c>\Re a>0$ with the change of variable
$$
v=\frac{u}{1-e^{-\lambda x}}.
$$